# при взаимодействии программы для android и сервера (php+mysql) некорректно отображается кириллица

Tags: php, android, mysql, кодировка, utf-8

Есть такой запрос:

```
$sql="UPDATE device` SET `Status` = '{$status}' , `Date` = Now() WHERE  `IMEI`='{$imei}'";
```

если в переменной `$status` хранятся символы английского алфавита, то запрос выполняется, а если русского — то нет.

кодировку указываю *utf-8*, *cp1251*.

данные в `$status` отправляются из *андроид*-программы. Причем, если при отправке не указывать кодировку, то запрос выполняется всегда, но вместо русских букв — «вопросики», а если указать кодировку, то вообще ничего не происходит.

но самое интересное, что назад на телефон вот такой строкой:

```
echo("rez={$status};");
```

значение переменной возвращается всегда, только без кодировки - вопросики, а если с кодировкой — то нормальные человеческие буквы.

в чём может быть причина такого поведения и как это исправить?

Comment: правильным решением будет использовать **везде** одну кодировку. а так как в программах для *android* стандартом де-факто является *utf8*, то и в *mysql*, и в *php*-скриптах надо использовать её же.

Comment: проголосовал за закрытие, так как проблема была решена [пересозданием столбца данных](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454310/#comment488903_454330)

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю вам стоит преобразовать кодировки к виду UTF-8 на php.Или же вы используете работу с utf-8 без mb_

http://www.gcmsite.ru/?pg=art&id=php-unicode-detect

http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php

В общем ваша задача найти кодировку и преобрзовать в UTF-8.
Или же отправлять и там и там. Но насколько я помню остальные кодировки считаются устаревшими

```
$text = iconv(‘utf-8′, ‘windows-1251′, $text);
если необходимо обратное действие, то:
$text = iconv(‘windows-1251′, ‘utf-8′, $text);
```

Comment: Переделал скрипт на get запрос, результат не изменился, получается андроид не виноват, куда копать не знаю

Comment: Все решил проблему, удалил столбец status в базе, и создал его по новому, и все заработало. всем спасибо кто пытался помочь

Answer (score 1):

БД должна быть в кодировке `utf8_general_ci` или `utf8_unicode_ci`
Такой вариант должен сработать:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '1111111', 'android');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf-8');
```

И не надо какие-то `iconv()` использовать или `mb_cobvert_encoding()`.
Их лучше использовать при работе с файлами.

И когда работаете с файлом в редакторе, то используйте кодировку **UTF-8 без BOM**